# Set default values of input with "multiple" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, database

I am using https://github.com/wpic/imageuplodify/ to upload multiple files to my server, but I would like to load the images from my database with ajax. I have an input that accepts multiple images like so

```html
  <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*">
```

My question is: How can I load the default images from my database table into the multiple input? The table holds and id (PK), and the picture url (in my server). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If i am correctly understanding you want to upload multiple images at  https://github.com/wpic/imageuplodify/ which are located at your server side in db. As you know the file names which user wants to upload at github, best approach is to take only file names as input from user and on server side write a (rest) client and upload the files into github repo instead of streaming the file data from server to user and sending it to github through client browser. 
Flow can be:
User -> select File names to Upload -> server -> rest client (read file data from db as stream) upload to github -> success -> User

Alternately,
if you want to do it from client side only then, we you can fetch the file data one by one from server and store it into localstorage and then pass it as stram to github on client side submit.

User -> select File names to Upload -> server -> responce(s) -> User -> store in localStorage -> read from local storage -> post the stream to github -> success msg

Comment: I can load the images to my frontend already, I want to know how to populate the multiple input with the images. For example, for a singular input, you can set val, but how do I accomplish this with multiple input?

Comment: As user is not uploading the files from his machine, you are just going to show the names of files in the normal input (just for his information) by generation the dynamic input boxes as per the list of file names and on submit you are going to push them to git one after the another from front-end.